# Градиент на QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, gui, интерфейс

Как сгладить градиент(на углах) на QPushButton?
Я имею такой код:

```
ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet(
                    "QPushButton {"
                    "background-color: lightGray;"
                    "border-style: solid;"
                    "border-width: 5px;"
                    "border-radius: 15px;"
                    "border-color: red;"
                    "padding: 10px;"
                    "}"

                    "QPushButton:checked{"
                    "border-top-color:qlineargradient(spread:pad,x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,"
                    "stop: 0 #000000, stop: 1 #c2c2c2);"
                    "border-left-color:  qlineargradient(spread:pad,x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0,"
                    "stop: 0 #000000, stop: 1 #c2c2c2);"
                    "border-right-color:  qlineargradient(spread:pad,x1: 1, y1: 1, x2: 0, y2: 1,"
                    "stop: 0 #000000, stop: 1 #c2c2c2);"
                    "border-bottom-color:  qlineargradient(spread:pad,x1: 1, y1: 1, x2: 1, y2: 0,"
                    "stop: 0 #000000, stop: 1 #c2c2c2);"
                    "}"
                    );
```

Результат исполнения программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нужно включить сглаживание в объекте *QPainter* используя `setRenderHints` метод. Это обычно делается при переопределении метода `paintEvent.`

Тебе нужно будет создать класс, который будет перехватывать события. Класс-фильтр установишь с помощью `QObject::installEventFilter`. Затем нужно создать объект *QPainter*, в конструктор которого передашь оригинальный объект. ( *QWidget* включает *QPaintDevice*)

```
filter::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event) {
QPainter painter(static_cast<QWidget *>(obj));
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
```

Comment: Не понятна последовательность действий. И "setRenderHints" или "setRenderHint" использовать?